# How to validate numeric strings in inputText with validateRegex in a JSF-Page

Tags: regex, validation, jsf, digits

I have a managed bean with this string property

`private String itemNumber;`

In the JSF I want to validate the input for length of 10 characters and allow only digits. The input will have preceding zeros. For example "0000123456"

```html
<h:inputText value="#{testBean.itemNumber}">
  <f:validateRegex pattern="\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d" />
</h:inputText>
```

On input of "asdf123456' I will get an beatiful validation message. 
But on input of "0000123456" I will get this exception

`java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.String`

What is wrong? Any ideas?

Comment: If you want all characters to be digits then why you are using a String type for itemNumber

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare the variable in the backing bean that is bound to your input text field as ***`Integer`***/***`Long`***/***`BigDecimal`*** and use

```
<f:validateLength maximum="10" minimum="10" />
```

instead of `<f:validateRegex pattern="\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d" />`.

Comment: Thanks! Now it runs. :)